# Rendering Template and its variable IN webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I am exploring webpy and facing one issue I don't know how to fix that.

As per doc. I found this is the way to render template and passing one variable to template.

```
render = web.template.render('templates')
print render.hello('world')
```

I used the same in my demo appw.

```
import web, sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))



urls = (
    '/', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self):
        render = web.template.render('templates/')
        name = 'Bob'    
        return render.home(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But Whenever I am running this code I keep getting error.

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /
__template__() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use a variable? Also what does your `home` template look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing `$def with(name)`

Try using this as your `home.html` template

```
$def with(name)
Hello $name
```

Think of `$def with()` as a function declaration. Whatever parameters you put in `$def with()` can be used as variables in your template. So if you have three parameters, then the render method for that template will expect three parameters like a normal function.

Example template:

```
$def with(name, todays_date, foods)

My name is $name

Today's date is $todays_date.date()

$for food in foods:
    $food
```

Example render call:

```
return render.home('Bob', datetime.now(), ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'])
```

On a side note, Webpy templates are kind of ugly, but you can basically use python logic, such as loops and lists. You need to use `$` to start python code.

Here is a link to the template docs for Webpy: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor

Comment: thanks Gohn but can you please explain why it is show .

Comment: @burning I added some additional information. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a headup,
if someone uses `$def with (args)`, it won't work either...
no white space should be in the middle between `with` and `()`